# Java generics unchecked warnings for extended classes

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
public class Foo {

    interface Coo<T> {
        public T cool();
    }

    abstract class Bar<T extends Bar<T>> implements Coo<T>  {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T doSomething() {
            return (T) this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public T cool() {
            return (T) this;
        }

    }

    class FooBar extends Bar<FooBar> {
        @Override
        public FooBar cool() {
            return super.cool();
        }

    }
}
```

Why is the cast to (this) object type unsafe? When Bar implements Coo, isn't the generic saying that returned cool must be of type T, which extends Bar or its subclasses?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems as though `Bar<T>` might be a better choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` in `Bar` has type `Bar<T extends Bar<T>>` but not `T`, the compiler generates warnings for `Bar#doSomething`. The following won't generate any warnings:

```
abstract class Bar<T extends Bar<T>> {

    Bar<T> doSomething() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

The body of `Bar#cool` expects `this` to be a subtype of `T` which is not the case. In `Bar#cool`, `this` has type `Bar<T extends Bar<T>>` and is a subtype of `Coo<T>` but not `T`.

Comment: If you got rid of the interface all together you'd still get the same warning.

Comment: Then what would be the correct way of doing this? I basically want to say that in cool(), I would like to return an object that is both a type of Bar (or its sublcass) and Coo.

Comment: @Student01: Given that `Bar` implements `Coo`, it's sufficient to return an object of type `Bar`.

Comment: @hoaz: Yes, I was just talking about `doSomething`.

Comment: i am stuck at the same place, it is interesting what he is trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

`T` extends `Bar<T>`, but `Bar<T>` (the type of `this`) does not extend `T`.

Imagine

```
class A extends Bar<A> { ... }
class B extends Bar<A> { ... }
```

Then the method becomes inherited as:

```
class B {
    A doSomething() {
        return (A) this;
    }
}
```

which is obviously not right.

It is not possible to do what you want with generics. It is a big misconception among people. They think that recursive bounds will allow you to do self-types. But recursive bounds are ALMOST NEVER useful in Java. 99% of the places where you see people write `interface Bar<T extends Bar<T>>`, it would be just as good to write it as `interface Bar<T>`.